# Lyx: insert \hline

Tags: lyx

Is there a command to insert a `\hline`? (Of course, ERT is always possible.)

I only see `>Insert>Formatting>Horizontal_line...` leading to

[image]

The output defaults to `\rule[0.5ex]{1\columnwidth}{1pt}`.

Comment: `\hline` is typically only used in tables.

Comment: Make a table with the "Insert table" button or the menu.  Or in a already made table, use  "set top line" or "set bottom line"  button in the table bar.  Both buttons add  `\hline` (except if you select a formal style in borders settings)

Comment: @Fran: Right, this would be the correct answer! I already do this. But my problem goes a little further, because I want a `\hline\hline` at the very top. Thus one \hline currently needs to go into an ERT.

Comment: Do not do that. Instead, check  the "formal style"  of borders, then remove *all* the lines, and finally make only the rules  for the top, bottom and after the header. That will change the `\hline`s  by `\toprule`,  `\bottomrule`   and `\midrule`. Of course, do not use vertical lines. Why these commands?  well, run `texdoc booktabs`  and see the page 2.